# Spring reading from properties file - @Value returns null

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have seen similar questions but none of the answers worked for me. I have a spring boot project and I am trying to read a value from my properties file in my OkHttpInterceptor class. Here is what I do:

```
@Component
public class MyInterceptor implements Interceptor{

    @Value("${api.key}")
    private String apiKey;

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Request newRequest;

        newRequest = request.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Token", apiKey)
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }
}
```

Here, apiKey returns null. But if I try the same in my RestController, i can read the value:

```
@RestController
public class PlatformController {

    @Autowired
    private PlatformService platformService;

    @Value("${api.key}")
    private String apiKey;
}
```

I also tried autowiring Environment in my interceptor class, and reading value using environment bu environment also returns null. What am i missing here?

My base package is com.myapp, and my interceptor is in the package named com.myapp.restclient. My SpringBootApplication class is like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my app.properties file:

```
api.key=xxxx-07dd6ff4c1ef
```

Thanks.

Comment: is the properties file in the same module? is there any additional property file configuration?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski yes, i have 3 properties file(application.properties, application-dev.properties and application-prod.properties) in src/main/resources folder. I also have no trouble reading value in my rest controller.

Comment: What package is the rest controller in?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski it is in com.myapp.controller

Comment: Are you sure that the value gets resolved in the controller? How do you know it?

Comment: Can you share the content of the properties file?

Comment: @senjin.hajrulahovic when I debug I see that value is resolved in controller.

Comment: @pelumi here is my properties file, I edited the question.

Comment: What is this interceptor? What creates it? If you aver do `new MyInterceptor()` in your code, then that's the problem: it needs to be instantiated by Spring. Not by you. Not by some other library like your rest client.